# How to extract value from the string in bash?

Tags: regex, git, bash, awk, sed

I have an input string in the following format:

```
bugfix/ABC-12345-1-00
```

I want to extract "ABC-12345". Regex for that format in C# looks like this:

```
.\*\\/([A-Z]+-[0-9]+).\*
```

How can I do that in a bash script? I've tried sed and awk but had no success because I need to extract value from the capturing group and skip the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your grep supports `-P` then you could use the below grep commands.

```
$ echo 'bugfix/ABC-12345-1-00' | grep -oP '/\K[A-Z]+-\d+'
ABC-12345
```

[`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)  keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

```
$ echo 'bugfix/ABC-12345-1-00' | grep -oP '(?<=/)[A-Z]+-\d+'
ABC-12345
```

`(?<=/)` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a `/` symbol.

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'bugfix/ABC-12345-1-00' | sed 's~.*/\([A-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\).*~\1~'
ABC-12345
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, my version of grep doesn't support -o, but sed version works just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've faced an issue with the sed solution: if I pass incorrect input ("master", for example), it shows "master" as output value instead of empty value.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "bugfix/ABC-12345-1-00"| perl -ane '/.*?([A-Z]+\-[0-9]+).*/;print $1."\n"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
echo "bugfix/ABC-12345-1-00" | egrep -o '[A-Z]+-[0-9]+'
OUTPUT:
ABC-12345
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like to use regex, you can use this `awk`:

```
echo "bugfix/ABC-12345-1-00" | awk -F\/ '{print $NF}'
ABC-12345-1-00
```

Or just this:

```
awk -F\/ '$0=$NF'
```